# my cursor is not showing next data row?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an Android application. I am using Sqlite database, four radio buttons, and one text view. When I click each radio button, it should display the next set of data from database.  Right now, it shows only first data row from the database. How can I change my code to make it show the appropriate row?

**Coding**

```
   db.open();
    try{

        final Cursor c = db.getAllQue();
        if(c != null)
        {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            int size = c.getCount();
            for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)

                quen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                anss1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                anss2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                anss3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                anss4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
                rgp1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                String ques = c.getString(0);
                String anes1 = c.getString(1);
                String anes2 = c.getString(2);
                String anes3 = c.getString(3);
                String anes4 = c.getString(4);
                String anes = c.getString(5);

                rgp1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
                        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)          findViewById(checkedId);
                         Toast.makeText(SqlliteActivity.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
                        c.moveToNext();
                    }
        });

                    quen.setText(ques);
                anss1.setText(anes1);
                anss2.setText(anes2);
                anss3.setText(anes3);
                anss4.setText(anes4);

            }

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Your logic of implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

isn´t your for iterating only this line ? `quen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

Also you are looking for each UI element inside the cursor iteration and the for...

But even if u add the braces to the for:

```
   db.open();
try{

    final Cursor c = db.getAllQue();
    if(c != null)
    {
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        int size = c.getCount();
        for(int i=0;i<=size;i++) {

            quen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            anss1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            anss2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            anss3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            anss4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
            rgp1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            String ques = c.getString(0);
            String anes1 = c.getString(1);
            String anes2 = c.getString(2);
            String anes3 = c.getString(3);
            String anes4 = c.getString(4);
            String anes = c.getString(5);

            rgp1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)          findViewById(checkedId);
                     Toast.makeText(SqlliteActivity.this, "" + radioButton.getText(),    2000).show(); 
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
         }
```

You will be setting the OnchangeListener a lot of times, but when you really clic on the button, if cursor its not closed you will move to the next record but your info will not be updated.

You should separate what is UI setting, button clic events and cursor or data management.

I think that the best approach could be:

- Make the query.
- Make a CursorAdaptor.
- When button/radioButton is clicked ask the adapter for the new position, this can retrieve an object with all the info.
- A method that populates your view is called.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Initiate your object elements outside of loop.

```
        quen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        anss1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        anss2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        anss3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        anss4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        rgp1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
```

use while loop to get next record.

```
db.open();
try{
    final Cursor c = db.getAllQue();
    if(c != null)
    {
       c.moveToFirst();
       do{
             //All your operations
             //everytime you will get next record.

         }while(moveToNext());
}
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printstack();
}
```